# Loop through layer from style

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I am trying to add a filter to my map, following this example:

https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/filter-markers/

My layer is called producers.

However I do not add my layer in the code, but on the mapbox website which means that I can't write like this in order to loop through the features in the layer:

```
 producers.features.forEach(function(feature) { ... }
```

What I have tried to do is the following:

```
var producers = map.getLayer('producers');

            producers.features.forEach(function (feature) { ... }
```

The features in my geojson file looks like this:

```
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
      11.9670171,
      57.7072326
    ]
  },
  "properties": {
    "marker-symbol": "symbol",
    "imageurl": "imageurl",
    "type": "type",
    "kWh": "number",
    "area":  "Place",
    "description": "description",
    "buttonurl":  "url"
  }
```

I have tried all different versions of accessing the different features in my layer:

```
producers.features.feature.producers.forEach(function (feature)
producers.features.feature.forEach(function (feature)
producers.features.producers.forEach(function (feature)
producers.features.forEach(function (feature)
```

But every try results in this kind of error:

> TypeError: producers.features is undefined

Does anybody know what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Explain more clearly what you are trying to do. Better with an example.

Comment: I have a map with a layer where the features have a property called "marker-symbol". The marker-symbol can be one of three values, and I want to be able to filter my map on them.
So, I want there to appear three little boxes (to begin with, I'd want to style them differently later) in the top corner of the map, one for each marker-symbol type. When you click one of the types, I want the map to only show t the features that have that property type.